# Python - Loop Over rows in a table and pass SQL parameters

Tags: python, sql, parameters

I'm trying to pass a row from a dataframe in a loop.  I want to use each element in the dataframe as a set of parameters for a SQL call.

```
     df = [1,2,3]#this would actually be a table with several rows import as a dataframe
     for row in df.itertuples:
        sql = 'Select * from table where a = ? and b = ? and c = ?'
        ds = pd.read_sql(sql, db_conn, params={row[1], row[2], row[3]})
        clf = LogisticRegression(ds)
```

This is the basic framework that I thought would work.  The idea is that I have a table that holds all the combinations that I need to create a logistic regression model.  I need a subset of a larger dataset based on several columns. I'm trying to cut down on bringing the whole dataset in at once.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to insert or retrieve the data? Are you looking for a way to parameterize your a,b and c? There can be many options that can be useful. At a basic level you can use limit in sql to limit the rows but still you question remains unclear to me.'

Comment: I've created a table with columns that hold values I want to pass as a SQL parameter for retrieving a subset of a SQL table.  So say my SQL table has 1 million rows.  The parameters when passed would break this up into the grouping I want to model.  I don't want just any chunking to happen, I want specific views of the data.

Comment: So what is not working for you?

Comment: When run the logic similar to the above and try to just print the "ds", I get database error:      "DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql" and the end of my query is displayed and the end of my query where the parameters would be pass, I see a bunch of unicode...\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00......  I know it's hard to diagnose without actual code, so I would take an answer in the form of "What is the best way to loop over a table and pass the entries of that table to a SQL query".  I'm trying to avoid pulling in the whole table before slicing it up the way I want...memory issues.

Comment: Well, in that case, I am wondering how your code reached till the sql execution with `itertuples` and not `itertuples()`

Comment: I was trying to just give the jist of the code.  The actual code is: for row in split_type.itertuples():    where split_type is all the different rows in the dataframe.  I think I'll just have to try a different way.  Thanks